# How to free memory of a double pointer in this case properly?

Tags: c, memory-leaks, malloc, free, dynamic-memory-allocation

My program is to increase a size of a struct array by creating new arr with a new size then assign the double pointer of the old array to the new one. I have been struggling with releasing memory of the old array before or after assigning it to the new one. If I don't fee(), it gives correct results, otherwise, it automatically pickup and print out some trash values. Please help, Thank you.

*realloc is not allowed.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct car {
    char name[30];
    int quantity;
};

void increaseSize(int *cap, int size, struct car **carArray) {
    printf("cap = %d size = %d\n", *cap, size);
    *cap *= 2;
    printf("cap x 2 = %d\n", *cap);
    struct car *newCarArray = (struct car * ) malloc(*cap * sizeof(struct car));
    memcpy(newCarArray, carArray, sizeof(struct car));
    free(*carArray); // If I free old carArray here, it will give incorrect results. How can I release/clear/delete/free the memory of the old array here?
    carArray = &newCarArray;
    printf("increased cap = %d size = %d\n", *cap, size);
}

void printArray(int cap, int size, struct car *carArray) {
    printf("Capacity = %d, Size = %d \n", cap, size);
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        printf("Car %d, Name: %s, Quantity: %d\n", i, carArray[i].name, carArray[i].quantity);
    }
}

int main() {

    int cap = 2;
    int size = 0;
    struct car *carArray = (struct car *) malloc(cap * sizeof(struct car));

    struct car car_0 = {"Corolla", 5};
    carArray[0] = car_0;
    size++;

    struct car car_1 = {"Accord", 8};
    carArray[1] = car_1;
    size++;

    printArray(cap, size, carArray);

    increaseSize(&cap, size, &carArray);

    struct car car_2 = {"Forte", 3};
    carArray[2] = car_2;
    size++;

    printArray(cap, size, carArray);
    free(carArray);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you heard of `realloc`?

Comment: @FiddlingBits I don't want to use realloc because it's not permitted.

Comment: `carArray = &newCarArray;` should be `*carArray = newCarArray;`.

Comment: `memcpy(newCarArray, carArray, sizeof(struct car));` copies *one* structure. Better learn how to use [`realloc`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/realloc).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude memcpy works even with array of struct, (tested)

Comment: This is just an uninteresting syntax bug where you assign the passed pointer incorrectly: `carArray = &newCarArray;`.

Comment: On a slightly related note, I think you're going about it all wrong. Instead of assigning structures explicitly, and then have a function to increase the capacity, I think you should create a "car container" structure, which have the information needed like capacity and the current size, and of course the pointer to the "array" itself. Then create a function to add a single car, passing name and quantity as arguments. That function will create the array if needed, or increase the size (through a separate function, like you do now).

Comment: [Continued] That makes it easier to abstract away the inner workings of the container, and makes it easier to test as well as easier to read, understand and maintain.

Comment: Not really related to your question, but you double the capacity of the array on each call without taking into account how many elements are used. You should first check if `size` is as large as `cap` and only then allocate a new array. Otherwise you will have many unused elements

Answer (score 4):

Two issues here.

First, you're only copying a *single* structure, not the whole array:

```
memcpy(newCarArray, carArray, sizeof(struct car));
```

Here, you're saying to copy `sizeof(struct car)` bytes, which is enough for one structure.  You're also not copying the right thing, since `carArray` is a pointer-to-pointer.  You need to multiply by the original size to copy the whole array, and you need to dereference `carArray`:

```
memcpy(newCarArray, *carArray, (*cap / 2) * sizeof(struct car));
```

The other problem is here:

```
carArray = &newCarArray;
```

Here, you're only modifying the parameter `carArray`, so changes to it aren't reflected in the caller.  You need to dereference it like you do `car`:

```
*carArray = newCarArray;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but after changing above, the problem is still, it's still printing incorrect results.

Comment: @LouisTran Please add missing important information: What output do you get and what do you expect. Please add it to the question. There you can also add the updated code. Please do not delete the old code which would invalidate all existing comments and answers.

Comment: @LouisTran You also need to dereference `carArray` in the `memcpy` call.  See my edit.